Error simple, se duplica el producto en el ticket, de mi sistema POS
Tengo un sistema Pos que estoy haciendo, pero tengo un error, el cual es asi: en la aplicacion hay botones para agregar productos sin codigo de barras, por ejemplo un pan, el comportamiento de estos botones son asi, al tocar el boton, te preguntara el precio del producto, y al aceptar se agrega como un producto cualquiera al carrito, al volver a agregar el mismo apartado, la cantidad del primer producto existente seguira igual, y el nuevo sera otro producto aparte, estos 2 productos no importa su apartado, siempre estan "aparte", ahora el problema que tengo es que al poner 2 veces el mismo apartado, en el ticket, la cantidad se sube a 2 en los 2 productos, que no deberia, y los dos productos, toman el mayor precio de esto, en el ticket el total se ve bien, pero en el ticket se ven como si estubieran duplicados, lo cual causa una confusion, el script puede ser largo pero puede servir para poner a prueba sus habilidades, el script es este https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XaMU6fgQuxpvcJDurw8YZE82KeDIKVqL?usp=drive_link, lo subo en google drive para que esten los demas elementos, y tambien por que no me deja poner el script completo, por que en total subrepasa el limite de caracteres es un desastre, pero es en parte uno de mis primeros scripts

This repository is empty dice el link que mandastes. Recuerda que el código del problema debe publicarse aquí. Puedes editar la pregunta para incluirlo.

el script puede ser largo pero puede servir para poner a prueba sus habilidades ... vaya, vaya.

Hola MrXkilerZ, bienvenido, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y agregues en ella (como texto) el código en cuestión, así evitarás que sea cerrada.

Oye, bien dificil el script, nisiquiera existe xD

@MrXkilerZ... estás totalmene loco (con todo respeto), jaja, mas de 800 lineas!!, yo te recomendaría que empezarás por refactorizar (muchas clases, cada una en un archivo, pocos métodos, pocas lineas), eso hará más fácil que alguien te ayude, y hasta te hará más sencillo a ti, encontrar los problemas.
